# How to use if statement in map function (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I want to use if statement in map function. Here is the code which I am using:

```
_collapsible() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.section}>
            <View style={CssHelper['flexRowCentered']}>
                { data['items'].map((item, index) =>
                    <FilterButton key={index} status={STATUS_DEFAULT_FILTER_BUTTON} style={styles.brandContainer}>
                        <ImageBackground style={styles.brand} source={item.source} resizeMode="contain"/>
                    </FilterButton>

                    //((index + 1) % 3 === 0) && <View style={CssHelper['verticalDivider']}></View>
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is more to do with returning multiple child components instead of a single component from your `.map` call - try wrapping the return value of the `map` function in a `<React.Fragment>`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you show me a little code snippet how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, The only thing is you miss a double bracket before the condition checking, Also please try to add a wrapper inside the map function to hold all the content, I have added a sample code for the same case with wrapper content inside map with flex:1

```
{ this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
    <View  style={{flex:1}} key={index}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        {  
        ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) && 
        <View style={{}}><Text>Third Row</Text></View> 
        } 
    </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

use ternary condition

```
{statment ? : null}
```